# FFMPEG: Issue with -t Option

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using `-t` option with output filename to generate the Output File with certain second provided with `-t` option.

Example Command,

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -i <input_fifo> -c copy -t 10 output.mp4
```

So For Example,

```
30 Frames * 10 Seconds = 300 Frames
```

`Output.mp4` should have 300 frames. But I am getting `Output.mp4` with less than 300 Frames like 272 frames and 290 frames etc.. Around 9+ Second content but not exact 10 Seconds.

Any one faces same behavior. Please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Logs that May help as asked by @Gyan,

```
Input file #0 (input_fifo.264):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 301 packets read (2559184 bytes); 
  Total: 301 packets (2559184 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (output.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 294 packets muxed (2509136 bytes); 
  Total: 294 packets (2509136 bytes) muxed
0 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
```

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking may be useful to you...also make sure you're using an up to date ffmpeg (for followers, seeking with "-c copy" can basically only seek to "i-frames" FWIW)

Comment: @rogerdpack the OP hasn't set a seek point, only recording duration. ffmpeg has to convey packets from start of stream so that can't be the reason here.

Comment: OP - share full log. Note that input `-r` has effect only for raw inputs.

Comment: maybe use ffprobe to see how many frames are actually timestamped less than 10s?

Comment: @rogerdpack:  how can i check that ? Little help/information will be good.

Comment: You can see all the packets with timestamps via something like `ffprobe -show_packets filename`